# Why is Chrome's download speed significantly lower?

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, download

Recently I've been having a lot of trouble with Chrome's download speeds. Upon starting up, everything is fine. However after a few minutes, ping latency and download speeds slow down to a crawl.

The strange thing is, upload speeds are fine and other browsers seem to do fine.

Chrome (20.0.1132.47 m on Windows 7):
[image: Screenshot showing speed]

Firefox:
[image: Screenshot showing speed]

This has been reproduced a number of times. It's very odd. Anyone have any idea as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Really weird. Maybe it has sth do do with the settings like max. parallel number of downloads etc. You can install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and try to figure out something perhaps by observing the behaviors in the session list.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone else comes across this issue, it could be browser extensions that are slowing things down.

Enter:

`chrome://extensions/`

Into the address bar and you can disable/enable (or delete if you want) any installed extensions and see if it makes any difference to your speed.